# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'search' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, function, syntax

Hi guys I new to this and I'm trying to create a search form, but seems to be a problem with my function php file.
I know for fact that the problem is in my "if" statement but I have no clue if there's any other option that i could use to make it work. Here's the code:

```
function my_search_form( $form ) {
$form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
<input type="text" name="s" id="search" align="center" size="30" value="' . get_searchform() . '" onfocus="if(this.value ==  . 'search & hit enter' . ) { this.value =  . '' . ; }" onblur="if(this.value ==  . '' . ) {this.value =  . 'search & hit enter' . ; }" />
<input type="hidden" value="post" name="post_type" id="post_type" />
</form>';

return $form;
```

}

```
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_search_form' );
```

Comment: You're using single quotes both to delimit your  `$form` string, as well as inside it around the javascript values. You'll need to escape the latter with backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
search & hit enter
```

This part is invalid code, it needs to be escaped

```
function my_search_form( $form ) {
    $form = '
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
        <input type="text" name="s" id="search" align="center" size="30" value="' . get_searchform() . '" onfocus="if(this.value == \'search &amp; hit enter\') { this.value = \'\'; }" onblur="if(this.value == \'\') {this.value =\'search &amp; hit enter\'; }" />
        <input type="hidden" value="post" name="post_type" id="post_type" />
    </form>';

    return $form;
}
```